Why don't the rotations cancel out in this composition: $R_\alpha \circ Z_{\vec{u}^\perp} \circ R_{-\alpha}$
I'm studying compositions of linear transformations, specifically rotations and reflections in the plane. Consider the following composition of transformations:
$
R_\alpha \circ Z_{\vec{u}^\perp} \circ R_{-\alpha}
$
where:

$ R_\alpha$ is the rotation by angle $ \alpha $ about the origin.
$ Z_{\vec{u}^\perp} $ is the reflection across the line perpendicular to the vector $ \vec{u} $.

Here's how I understand this composition:

First Rotation $R_{-\alpha}$: We rotate the entire plane (including $ \vec{u} $ and any vector $ \vec{v} $ we're transforming) by $ -\alpha $ radians.

Reflection $Z_{\vec{u}^\perp}$: We reflect vectors across the line perpendicular to $\vec{u}'$, where $\vec{u}' = R_{-\alpha}(\vec{u}) $. So the reflection depends on the rotated vector $\vec{u}' $.

Second Rotation $ R_{\alpha}$: We rotate the plane back by $ \alpha $ radians.


Intuitively, I would think that the two rotations $ R_{-\alpha} $ and $ R_{\alpha} $ would cancel each other out, leaving us with just the reflection $ Z_{\vec{u}^\perp} $. However, I've been told that they do not cancel out because the reflection occurs with respect to the rotated vector $ \vec{u}' $, and thus the effect of the rotations remains in the composition.
I'm struggling to understand why the rotations don't cancel out in this context. If we rotate everything by $ -\alpha $ and then by $ \alpha $, shouldn't we end up back where we started, effectively neutralizing the rotations? How does the fact that the reflection is with respect to $ \vec{u}' $ prevent the rotations from canceling out?
Could someone please explain why the rotations do not cancel out in this composition?
Thanks a lot!

Just visualize it. What happens on the plane if you rotate counterclockwise 45 degrees, reflect about the x-axis, then rotate clockwise 45 degrees? What happens to the basis vectors?

I suggest trying this with a piece of paper. Actually, a book works.

@ArturoMagidin Hmm not sure I get it, shouldn't I reflect about the rotated j basis vector then? Why the x-axis?

The reflection is about $u$, not about wherever $u$ goes. That's one major error you are committing. The reflection is fixed.

Hmm ok, I understand now, for some reason I thought the whole plane gets rotated and the basis vectors get rotated as well, which would mean if $\vec{u} = (2, 1)$ then after rotation it would be $2 \textbf{i}' + 1\textbf{j}'$ so $\vec{u}$ was transformed as well. Thanks a lot!

The image of $u$ is not $u$, but $Z$ is "reflect about the vector perpendicular to $u$", not "reflect about the vector perpendicular to wherever $u$ goes". If $Z(x,y) = (x,-y)$, then this map doesn't change just because you are pre-composing or post-composing with something else.

Less conceptually but more concretely, compute the matrix product explicitly: $$\begin{bmatrix}\cos\alpha & -\sin\alpha \ \sin\alpha & \cos\alpha \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\cos\alpha & \sin\alpha \ -\sin\alpha & \cos\alpha\end{bmatrix}$$ and see what happens.

Thinking about what exactly you reflect about isn't helping you clearing up this problem in understanding. You reflect about something, which is never mentioned or needed again, so it isn't really important what exactly it is, it is some line. Your problem in understanding is the effect that this reflection has on the orientation of the image of the plane.
